# jQuery ColorBox close button triggering postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery colorBox which pops up a userControl with some html controls in it.

The colorBox is launched when the user clicks a link with the "colorBoxLink" class:

```
$j(".colorBoxLink").click((function () {
            $j("div#popup").show();
            var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("wysihtml5_textarea", { // id of textarea element
                toolbar: "wysihtml5-toolbar", // id of toolbar element
                parserRules: wysihtml5ParserRules, // defined in parser rules set 
                stylesheets: ["Styles/wysihtml5.css", "Styles/wysihtml5.css"]
            });

            $j.colorbox({
                inline: true,
                href: "#popup",
                modal: true,
                scrolling: false,
                onCleanup: function () {
                    $j("div#popup").hide();
                }

            });

        }));
```

If I click off the control it closes as required (i.e. if the user decides not to add any content). However, if the user clicks the "x" button on the colorBox it causes postback and the page reloads.

How do I stop this?

Comment: what kind of button this is x. Means asp.net button or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the javascript function. Then it will not postback.

```
 $j(".colorBoxLink").click((function () {
        $j("div#popup").show();
        var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("wysihtml5_textarea", { // id of textarea element
            toolbar: "wysihtml5-toolbar", // id of toolbar element
            parserRules: wysihtml5ParserRules, // defined in parser rules set 
            stylesheets: ["Styles/wysihtml5.css", "Styles/wysihtml5.css"]
        });

        $j.colorbox({
            inline: true,
            href: "#popup",
            modal: true,
            scrolling: false,
            onCleanup: function () {
                $j("div#popup").hide();
            }

        });
        return false;
    }));
```

Comment: It's still posting back using this. :-( Is this the right place for the return false; ?

Comment: Set breakpoint and check where the end of the statement is. Then place return there...

Answer (score 0):

Colorbox's close button is actually a button element, which causes ASP to interpret it as part of a form and to try to submit what is on the page. You need to create a fake close button that looks the same (look at the colorbox.css code for this) but is either a  or an  tag instead of a  tag, and either remove the close button through javascript or hide it in the css using an !important tag. You can reference the close button using the id "cboxClose". Your fake close button should call jQuery.colorbox.close(); on click.